# Как сверстать параллакс на заднем плане, с условием, что кристаллы на разных слоях?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, parallax

[image]
Например три разных слоя с группами кристаллов. Как сверстать, спозиционировать эти группы, чтобы они не перекрывали информацию?

Comment: Зачем усложнять?Склейте слои в редакторе.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yqfy5DaTqlw  вот видео по данному вопросу , https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax это гит репа - там вообще подробно описано..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как например, использовать [parallax.js](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/):

```js
var sceneF = document.getElementById('scene-forward');
var parallaxInstance = new Parallax(sceneF);

var sceneB = document.getElementById('scene-backward');
var parallaxInstance = new Parallax(sceneB);
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;  
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(53,93,115,1);
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(53,93,115,1) 0%, rgba(32,59,73,1) 100%);
}

.section{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem 4rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

.section-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: light;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  z-index: 10;
}

.section-body {
  max-width: 30rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: .875rem;
  line-height: 1.25rem; 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.scene,
.layer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#scene-forward {
  z-index: 5;
}

#scene-backward {
  z-index: 20;
}

.layer svg {
  position: absolute;
}

#pin-1 {
  transform: scale(.5);
  left: 5%;
  bottom: 30%;
}

#pin-2 {
  transform: scale(.45) rotate(20deg);
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 30%;
}

#pin-3 {  
  transform: scale(.15) rotate(45deg);
  right: -10%;
  bottom: -40%;
}

#pin-4 {
  transform: scale(.2) rotate(60deg);
  right: 0%;
  bottom:10%;
  filter: blur(10px);
}

#pin-5 {
  transform: scale(.5) rotate(10deg);
  left: 20%;
  bottom:10%;
  filter: blur(4px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax/3.1.0/parallax.min.js"></script>
  
  
  <div class="section">
    <h2 class="section-title">Три основных требования</h2>

    <div class="section-body">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque, ullam molestiae maxime! Deserunt similique at iure iste odit dolore rem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, fugiat!
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, ratione ducimus dolorum et quisquam impedit temporibus reiciendis aut delectus! Autem rem, doloremque reprehenderit tempore voluptatem natus asperiores delectus vel aliquam.
      </p>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div id="scene-forward" class="scene">
      <div data-depth="0.30" class="layer">
        <svg id="pin-1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="185.5" height="198.2">        
          <path style="fill:#3d6b84; stroke:#213c4b;" d="m 0.6,127.9 146.3,7 12.3,-134.3 z"/>        
          <path style="fill:#213c4b; stroke:#213c4b;" d="m 146.9,135 38,62.6 -25.7,-197 z"/>
          <path style="fill:#3d6b84; stroke:#3d6b84;" d="m 0.6,127.9 184.3,69.7 -38,-62.6 z"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
      
      <div data-depth="0.2" class="layer">
        <svg id="pin-2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="185.5" height="198.2">        
          <path style="fill:#42738d; stroke:#42738d;" d="m 0.6,127.9 146.3,7 12.3,-134.3 z"/>        
          <path style="fill:#325a6f; stroke:#325a6f;" d="m 146.9,135 38,62.6 -25.7,-197 z"/>
          <path style="fill:#30566a; stroke:#30566a;" d="m 0.6,127.9 184.3,69.7 -38,-62.6 z"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
      
      <div data-depth="0.1" class="layer">
        <svg id="pin-4" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"width="840.28003" height="831.63">
          <g transform="translate(15.867334,-52.584961)" id="layer1">
            <path style="fill:#325a6f; stroke:#325a6f;" d="M -7.8670514,382.07993 L 312.55097,876.19257 L 387.19552,410.6131 L -7.8670514,382.07993 z "/>
            <path style="fill:#325a6f; stroke:#325a6f;" d="M 816.41241,579.50922 L 312.52667,876.21687 L 387.19552,410.6131 L 816.41241,579.50922 z "/>
            <path style="fill:#30566a; stroke:#30566a;" d="M -7.8670514,382.07993 L 527.24183,60.583059 L 387.19552,410.6131 L -7.8670514,382.07993 z "/>
            <path style="fill:#325a6f; stroke:#325a6f;" d="M 816.37325,579.50922 L 527.24183,60.583059 L 387.19552,410.6131 L 816.37325,579.50922 z "/>
            <path style="fill:#3e6a83; stroke:#3e6a83;" d="M -7.8670514,382.07993 L 527.24183,60.583059 L 458.19552,594.6131 L -7.8670514,382.07993 z"/>
            <path style="fill:#42738d; stroke:#42738d;" d="M -7.8670514,382.07993 L 312.55097,876.19257 L 458.19552,594.6131 L -7.8670514,382.07993 z"/>
            <path style="fill:#2f566a; stroke:#2f566a;" d="M 816.41241,579.50922 L 312.52667,876.21687 L 458.19552,594.6131 L 816.41241,579.50922 z "/>
            <path style="fill:#325a6f; stroke:#325a6f;" d="M 816.37325,579.50922 L 527.24183,60.583059 L 458.19552,594.6131 L 816.37325,579.50922 z "/>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
      
      <div data-depth="0.15" class="layer">
        <svg id="pin-5" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="185.5" height="198.2">        
          <path style="fill:#42738d; stroke:#42738d;" d="m 0.6,127.9 146.3,7 12.3,-134.3 z"/>        
          <path style="fill:#325a6f; stroke:#325a6f;" d="m 146.9,135 38,62.6 -25.7,-197 z"/>
          <path style="fill:#30566a; stroke:#30566a;" d="m 0.6,127.9 184.3,69.7 -38,-62.6 z"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="scene-backward" class="scene">      
      <div data-depth="0.8" class="layer">
        <svg id="pin-3" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"width="840.28003" height="831.63">
          <g transform="translate(15.867334,-52.584961)" id="layer1">
            <path style="fill:#325a6f; stroke:#325a6f;" d="M -7.8670514,382.07993 L 312.55097,876.19257 L 387.19552,410.6131 L -7.8670514,382.07993 z "/>
            <path style="fill:#325a6f; stroke:#325a6f;" d="M 816.41241,579.50922 L 312.52667,876.21687 L 387.19552,410.6131 L 816.41241,579.50922 z "/>
            <path style="fill:#30566a; stroke:#30566a;" d="M -7.8670514,382.07993 L 527.24183,60.583059 L 387.19552,410.6131 L -7.8670514,382.07993 z "/>
            <path style="fill:#325a6f; stroke:#325a6f;" d="M 816.37325,579.50922 L 527.24183,60.583059 L 387.19552,410.6131 L 816.37325,579.50922 z "/>
            <path style="fill:#3e6a83; stroke:#3e6a83;" d="M -7.8670514,382.07993 L 527.24183,60.583059 L 458.19552,594.6131 L -7.8670514,382.07993 z"/>
            <path style="fill:#42738d; stroke:#42738d;" d="M -7.8670514,382.07993 L 312.55097,876.19257 L 458.19552,594.6131 L -7.8670514,382.07993 z"/>
            <path style="fill:#2f566a; stroke:#2f566a;" d="M 816.41241,579.50922 L 312.52667,876.21687 L 458.19552,594.6131 L 816.41241,579.50922 z "/>
            <path style="fill:#325a6f; stroke:#325a6f;" d="M 816.37325,579.50922 L 527.24183,60.583059 L 458.19552,594.6131 L 816.37325,579.50922 z "/>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

На весь экран лучше смотреть.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/JpXVgG)

Comment: Отлично! Как всегда. Тлен проходит?

Comment: Тлен? =)) уже хроническая форма)

Comment: Держись. *Всё проходит,- и это пройдёт* Так было написано на кольце царя Соломона.

Comment: "Всё проходит,- и это пройдёт  ... мимо!" на моем кольце)

Comment: всё равно держись

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте большой div с позицией absolute, в котором весь сайт, а треугольники задать фоном к div-ам. Для парралакса можно использовать parallax.js. Если возникнут проблемы с позицией, надо задать z-index (чем больше, тем выше слой элемента с позицией absolute/relative)